# Why is ROS slower than a normal TCP connection?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why is ROS connections slower than a normal TCP socket connect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277749/why-is-ros-slower-than-a-normal-tcp-connection?/) by [Dhivin](https://answers.ros.org/users/27282/dhivin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-11**:
Can you clarify what is slower? Setting up connection, sending data (and then: bw or latency), tearing them down, something else?

**Comment by [Dhivin](https://answers.ros.org/users/27282/dhivin/) on 2017-12-11**:
I mean while sending and receiving data its slower than a TCP socket connection without ROS framework.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-11**:
How are you measuring this? If you are comparing sending a raw array of bytes versus publishing and receiving messages, then that is not a correct comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROSTCP is an adapter that lets ROS send messages over TCP for topics; not for general use.

If you want a TCP socket, use the standard OS interface for creating a TCP socket.

Please check this

https://github.com/abhinavjain241/comm_tcp

---

Originally posted by [Arjun S Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27661/arjun-s-kumar/) with karma: 16 on 2017-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dhivin](https://answers.ros.org/users/27282/dhivin/) on 2017-12-11**:
Not what i am asking.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-11**:
If this is not what you asked, then why did you mark the question as *answered*?